# Error configuring a second instance of jquery for use a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

Hi guys I'm trying to configure two instance of jquery in my struts2 project, both with different versions(2.1.1 and 1.4) one is configure through struts2-jquery-plugin-2.5.0.jar and the other through .js file, and I configured with the following code:

```
<script src="/Pages/Menu/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script >var $stef = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src="/Pages/Menu/js/fixedTblLftCol/jquery.fixedTblHdrLftCol.js"></script>
```

so when I tried to execute the following code:

```
           $stef("#tblEditarMstRutas").fixedTblHdrLftCol({
                scroll: {
                    height: '200px',
                    width: '550px',
                    leftCol: {
                        fixedSpan: 3
                    }
                }
            });
```

I configured the struts2-jquery-plugin in my project through intellij and I used the following code in my .jps

```
  <sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond" />   
  <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
```

the web browser shown the error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function, somebody could help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you load `struts2-jquery-plugin` jQuery?

Comment: I configured the struts2-jquery-plugin in my project through intellij , I edited the answer explain how to.

Comment: You need to load both jQuery and then call `noConflict` and your `$stef` variable will be the second jQuery that you loaded.

Comment: The last version you load overrides the first one, so you have no conflict.

Comment: Post the whole head section of the *rendered* HTML, not the JSP